# Couldn't read row 384, col 47 from CursorWindow. Make sure the Cursor is initialized correctly

Tags: java, android, sqlite, cursor, android-cursoradapter

I'm reading some data from Android calendar and sometimes I got strange crash reports from users like:

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Couldn't read row 384, col 47 from CursorWindow. 
Make sure the Cursor is initialized correctly before accessing data from it.
```

My code is here (bold is line where app crashes):

```
        Cursor eventCursor = contentResolver.query
            (builder.build(), 
            null, 
            CalendarContract.Instances.CALENDAR_ID + " IN (" + ids  + ")", 
            null, 
            null);

        if (eventCursor == null)
            return true;

        while (eventCursor.moveToNext()) {  //this line causecrash
            ... do something...
        }
```

Why this happens? It can't be simulated. It never ever happened to me and I just can't understand reason nor the error message.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the beginning of your iteration use [`eventCursor.moveToFirst()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/Cursor.html#moveToFirst%28%29) to move to the first row. You may use something like this:

```
if (eventCursor != null) {

    //Start from beginning
    eventCursor.moveToFirst();

    // Loop over rows
    while (eventCursor.moveToNext()) {

        // Do Somehing here
    }
 }
```

You can also check whether the Cursor has rows or not by using [`eventCursor.getCount()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/Cursor.html#getCount%28%29).